# HighCharts starts zooming when scrolling in a 3D chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If both scrolling and zooming is enabled in a HighCharts **3D** chart, and you drag the scrollbar to move along the x-axis, you simultaneously create a zooming rectangle and end up zooming in on the chart when you release the mouse button.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cxEu/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 15,
            beta: 15,
        },
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 2,
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    }, {
        name: 'Janet',
        data: [3, 1, 4, 4, 3],
    }]
});
```

If the chart is **2D**, scrolling works as expected - not interfering with the zoom functionality (in the jsFiddle, just comment out *options3d.enabled*).

Is there a way to get the 3D chart working as expected too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3131